# Getting Started with iOS MDM service

Tags: ios, mdm

I want to start with iOS MDM service. Plan is to do a proof of concept, first get a feel for iOS MDM api and then propose it to my manager.Few question regarding that:

1. Is Enterprise Developer Account required just for the POC purpose? My understanding is Enterprise Account would be needed for distribution purpose only.
2. What are the tutorials available for MDM api?
3. I came across [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html) document which gives a good introduction of MDM service. Is there any other similar document available?

Comment: I'm a bit lost as to why this question was down voted... it seems perfectly valid to me.

Comment: Please see edited answer below. Apple has given me a viable path to work with them for small start-ups such as this one. Recommend taking this off the closing block.

Comment: @D80Buckeye, I agree.  Too many people here with nothing better to do than censor other peoples' questions.  If you want to see the question reopened, do as I did, and use the `reopen` link below the question.

Comment: the answer to this question has changed. an enterprise account is not required and the documentation is now publicly available. https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1) Yes - you're going to need an Enterprise Account AND let Apple know you want access to the MDM documentation and libraries. If you're doing your work on behalf of a company I would recommend finding your local Apple Rep in CT. I have a pretty good idea as to who your rep out there is so let me know if that's the case.

2) You may be able to dig up some tutorials (or people that know some) on [EnterpriseiOS.com](http://www.enterpriseios.com) though that site is hit & miss. If you're looking to do everything from scratch (including the APNs server) there are a lot of git projects out there that handle it.

3) Once you take care of step 1 there are some other documents out on the Apple site that discuss the calls in detail. [This document](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf) covers a lot of the protocol as well.

Good luck!

EDIT:
Anyone looking to take this route can contact Apple Developer Relations at 1 (800) 633-2152 Mon-Fri 9:00AM-7:00PM CST.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have few doubts on signing up for Enterprise Account. Can I email you those questions directly?

Comment: Hit me up on twitter for now - same username.

Comment: @Dan Hi Dan  I read the mdm protocol pdf & have understood most of the thing but not able clear myself what are the various steps for coding. I have done all certificates part from here https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server. Please help me for the rest of the parts.

Comment: an enterprise account is not required and the documentation is now publicly available. https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf

Comment: @respectTheCode seems like they've changed the process 5 1/2 years after my answer. Feel free to submit your own.

Comment: The question was closed so it can't be answered. I just wanted to get the link out there. Its not clear when apple made the docs available.